# How do i change colors for overlapping events in fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am doing a project on Asp. Net MVC and I am trying to implement Jquery fullcalendar.

I want a newly added event to change its color if the event already exists for that day.

Thank you

Comment: Have you got a JSON reply to your fullCalendar?
Or please specify- about your event source.

Comment: Yes everything else is working fine, I just want a newly added event to change its color if it exists already for that particular date and time.

http://s11.postimg.org/7rie5vqjn/Overlap.png

I want the 2nd event to have its color changed..

Comment: How do you add that event? I mean the source?

Answer (score 0):

I found the best answer for you:

Some new changes to the fc-event-skin class... it's now only fc-event, so styling shouldn't be an issue. Please check author's note here  [fullcalendar fc-event class](https://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=944#c10)...

The best approach is to set the className in the event object and add it to the elements found by an 'fc-event-skin' class. However, your added class will come later in the css and the colors will not take precedence, so you have to use !important. This also preserves the "fake" rounded corners...

Wire this method up on the calendar...

```
eventRender:
function (event, element, view) {
    element.find('.fc-event-skin').addClass(event.className.join(' '));
}
```

This in your own style sheet...

```
.redGray
{
    border-color: DarkGray !important;
    background-color: LightGray !important;
    color: red !important;
}
```

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

I think this is a minor bug in the rendering code. The element parameter is an jQuery object, so you can modify that based on your custom event data. If you set the style and text of the element, it will render with the color you set; however, it appears to me that other styles are removed from the element such as the rounded corners and the formatting of the time and text.

```
eventRender: 
function (event, element) {
    if (event.LeadId != null) {
        element.css('color', 'blue');
        element.css('background-color', 'yellow');
        element.text(element.text);
    }
```

Reference: [Fullcalendar doesn't render color when using eventRender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7918301/fullcalendar-doesnt-render-color-when-using-eventrender)